# Wicket - SetResponsePage callback not firing

Tags: wicket

I'm writing my first wicket app , and ran into my first road-block today . Here's the problem .
I have a page which contains an AjaxSubmitLink . In it's onSubmit event , I load a panel using setResponsePage .

From the homepage of my app , I can navigate to the above mentioned page in 2 ways - either by a hyperlink or by switching a tab (use a basic ITab from wicket-extensions), both of which invokes the same constructor with identical arguments.

Now if I navigate to the page using the hyperlink , everything works fine . However , if I use the tab to navigate to the page , the AjaxSubmitLink doesnt load the panel . There's an Ajax request being made , I can see the server processing it , but it's like no callback is being executed .

Another strange thing I noticed , in the latter case , firebug doesn't log my Ajax requests on the console . It logs requests in the former case just fine .

I'm kinda stumped here , any hints,pointers or nudges ?

Edit : Code declaring the link .

```
 editLink = new AjaxSubmitLink("editLink") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> masterForm) {
                    setResponsePage(new EditPage(programId));
            }
        };
```

Edit : I inspected the requests made with fiddler , the unsuccessful Ajax calls are returning a 302 , instead of 200.

UPDATE :

I kinda found a workaround . The fiddler information lead me to search for the setResponsePage behaviour , which lead me to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1703 .

Anyway since I didnt strictly need a POST request for the link , used a GET instead to get the desired behaviour .

Interesting find using fiddler : the content-type of the request sent is multipart/form-data rather than application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the erroneous case.

I'm still kind of in the dark on the actual issue , appreciate any explanations .

Comment: `setResponsePage()` uses web pages, not web components (panels in this case). Can we see some of your code to try to help you?

Comment: code provided . I'm not sure which part to post . Also fiddler tells me that the requests are returning with a 302 .

Comment: What's the purpose of using an AjaxSubmitLink if all you do is redirect to a different page? If you have to do a complete page reload anyway, why not use a normal SubmitLink?

Comment: good question . And I just logged in to comment I shouldn't be using the AjaxSubmitLink anyway . The wicket code samples around me seem to have affected my ability to think straight .:)

Answer (score 0):

`setResponsePage()` should get a .class file or a instantiated class instead. like

```
NextPage np = new NextPage(int a,int b);
....
setResponsePage(np);
```

or

```
setResponsePage(NextPage.class);
```

Comment: It can happen that you even need to pass a value to NextPage. Then you can use setResponsePage(new NextPage(var1)).